# Images under sites/default/files not appearing

Tags: media, .htaccess

I have images inside `/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/field/image`, and I can't seem to see them in my browser, I have /sites permission set to 777 and I read something about commenting all the `Options` line from my .htaccess. And here's my .htaccess :

```
# Turn off all options we don't need.
#Options None
#Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

Any way I can solve this ?

Comment: Have you gave recursive permission to the sites folder?

Comment: Yes The permission to the folder and all it subfolder are set to (777)

Comment: Please give permission like : chmod -R 777 /sites. It will give permission to the inner files and folders too(used -R in command).Just having an idea that your inner files or folder do not have permission. Just check it?

Comment: I'm on windows filezilla.

Comment: Which error did You get when try to access any image from this directory? 403, 404 or something else?

Comment: Have you tried to open image link in new tab?

Answer (score 0):

- First of all give recursive permissions to the folder (sites folder).
  Below screenshot shows how to give recursive permission on windows
  filezilla.

Select the checkbox "Recurse into subdirectories"
[image]

- Make sure to reset the permissions on the settings.php file